# Make a ContextMenu on TextField / TextEditors in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Hello friends of swift coding,

I try to create a contextMenu on TextEditor and TextField in SwiftUI for my macOS app.

```
TextEditor(text: $information)
    .contextMenu{
        Button {
            print("gogogo")
        } label: {
            Text("Just do it!")
        }
    }
```

Code above is not working. What I try to achieve: in a TextEditor I like to right-click and either make changes to selected text or paste some textclippings to a certain position.
But the contextMenu inside an editor seems to be different to the contextMenu of other UI-Views.
How is it done, then? Or can I use the above code and have to put it somewhere else or give it a code word?